# TripleDES Decryption in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, tripledes

```
TripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
this.GenerateKey(); //Generate Key ..
TripleDES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
TripleDES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;



byte[] cipher = new byte[0];
ICryptoTransform ict = TripleDES.CreateEncryptor();
cipher = ict.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Hi when i decypt the message using the same instance of the `TripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();` works properly but when i try to dcrypt using a **new instance** it says "Bad Data"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are generating a new key on each run. Try giving a static key instead of using `this.GenerateKey();`.